# ERP seems not being interpreted in database.yml and secrets.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, environment-variables, yaml

My rails-app seem not to interpret the lines

```
password: <%= ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

in *database.yml* and

```
secret_key_base: <%= ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"] %>
```

in *secrets.yml*.

When I paste both values directly into these files, my app works.

Through **rails console** I got sure that

```
ENV['MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD']
ENV["SECRET_KEY_BASE"]
```

have valid values.

According the Rails documentation, rails parses ERB in those files.

This seems a bug for me, because this is all generated code by rails. I use Rails 4.2.1, so ERB should work in those file.

I like this approach, does anyone have an idea how to activate ERB in those files?

Comment: quite curious, you shouldn't have to activate this. Did you restart your rails application after adding those ENV variables?

Comment: Jep I restarted even the whole system.

Comment: where are you setting/did you set the environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's solved.

rails console env gets the environment variables from the shell, but nginx/passenger don't. This is why it works for me just in the console.

You have so set the ENV-vars in the site-config of your nginx-server:

```
passenger_env_var MYAPP_DATABASE_PASSWORD <db_password>;
passenger_env_var SECRET_KEY_BASE  <secret_key>;
```

That's it!!!